# How to access ng-model value in controller of popup model in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to access an ngModel from within a controller, but here the ngModel is defines in a popup input field.  I want to access the qty and name values in controller. Note that this whole code is model popup.

#### Model code

```
<ion-modal-view> 
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Item Details</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <form ng-submit="addItem()">
            <div class="list list-inset">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Qty</span>
                    <input type="number" name="qty" ng-model="qty">
                </label>
                <div class="padding item text-center">
                    <button class="button button-dark">Add To Cart</button>
                    <a class="button  button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</a>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

#### Controller code

```
.controller('GuestDetailsCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        alert($scope.name);
        alert($scope.qty);
    }; 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this view has the GuestDetailsCtrl assigned? Because this code should be working

Comment: If the bit of html code you posted is under the same controller as the popup, you should be able to access the values with $scope.name or $scope.qty, you could try as a test to make a <label ng-model=name> on your main page and see if it's filled after you submit your popup

Comment: i have tested in label value filled but in controller alert message displayed "undefined".

Comment: Can you post the code/html where you assign your controller to this view?

Comment: I think as NexusDuck mentioned, you should tell the pop-up window to use GuestDetailsCtrl. So something like: `<ion-modal-view ng-controller="GuestDetailsCtrl">`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to give params in the function like this :

```
<ion-modal-view> 
<ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Item Details</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content padding="true">
    <form ng-submit="addItem(params)">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="params.name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Qty</span>
                <input type="number" name="qty" ng-model="params.qty">
            </label>
            <div class="padding item text-center">
                <button class="button button-dark">Add To Cart</button>
                <a class="button  button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

And in your controller :

```
   .controller('GuestDetailsCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.addItem = function(params) {
          alert(params.name);
          alert(params.qty);
      }; 
  });
```

Comment: This is a bit of a hack though imo